# Getting count from firebase nested objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the below scenario[image]

Attempting the below fails:

```
  this._directChatsRef = this.db.list(`users/${this.authProvider.getUID()}/chat`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'read',
      equalTo: false
    }
  });
  this._directChatsRef.subscribe((directChats) => {
    this._chats = directChats.length;
  });
```

I know there's an object right above the `chat` object, but how can I return just the array of chat objects from firebase with the specified query?

The purpose of this is to get a count of `unread` messages.

Thanks!

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order on properties at a *known path* under each node of the location where you run the query. It seems like your current structure does not meet that requirement. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: Downloading all unread messages to show their count is rather wasteful of the user's bandwidth. If your app has the need to show the number of unread messages, I'd recommend keeping that precise property in your database.